# Is the order of function calls during QML object initialization deterministic?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a C++ plugin for QML that has some properties and I am wondering if there is some documentation regarding what order the functions will be called in the following QML code:

```
MyCustomThing {
   propertyA: 20   // Will putting this line first guarantee A before B?
   propertyB: 30
}
```

On my machine things happen in the opposite order I'd expect (in this case B before A, i.e. whatever appears last in the QML is the first thing invoked), but it would be nice to know if this is consistent across platforms - and ideally documented somewhere.

Is there any documentation specifying the order of function calls during QML object construction?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "width" in the code comment?

Comment: A typo, sorry. Thanks for finding it, I've edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order is undefined, and you should not depend on it.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to do something when both `propertyA` and `propertyB` are set to values declared in your qml file.

You can override [QQuickItem::componentComplete](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickitem.html#componentComplete). It will be called when all properties are set to initial values. Just don't forget to call super class in the beginning of your overriding method.

```
void MyCustomThingItem::componentComplete()
{
    QQuickItem::componentComplete();
    // continue initialization 
    myCustomInit(m_propertyA, m_propertyB); // guaranteed to be 20 and 30
}
```

Edit:
QML equivalent would be:

```
MyCustomThing {
    propertyA: 20
    propertyB: 30
    Component.onCompleted: {
        myCustomInit(propertyA, propertyB); // 20, 30
    }
}
```